# Will my friends know if I delete them?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

When I installed StarCraft 2, I added all my "friends" from Facebook. The thing is I'm not really in touch with most of them, so I would like to trim the list a bit.

Do people you delete get notified when you delete them?

Comment: If they're not really your friends, will they really care?

Comment: As I said, they're Facebook Friends :)

Comment: does it add all your facebook friends or just the ones who actually have battle.net and sc2?

Comment: Just those that have b.net and sc2, and you manually select.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notified? No, but they can see that you're no longer in their friend's list.